# Is there an internal process in the JEE server to kill/free lost sessions?

Tags: jboss, cdi, apache-tomee, payara

My webapp runs Payara4+JSF2.2+CDI2.
Somentimes the user closes the browser, or closes the browser tab (my webapp may run many tabs),
or until browser or client OS crash.
Then, I would like to know if there is some internal process in JEE server like Payara/Glassfish/JBoss/Tomee/etc that monitors this situation to free the memory used by all objects (CDI injected beans, other objects used ny the webapp in the server, etc) in the user session lost, like a
JEE server garbage collection (not the default Java garbage collection).
This is a problem in a webapp environment with many users, the memory consuming becomes very big with trash objects.

Comment: There is... it's called session timeout... And if the sessions are too big, maybe your design is wrong. Better to (also, or rather first) fix that

Comment: For example, there is a report where the user may need info from all the year, there are many records in the database, some calculations to do, and if the user fills init/final date interval larger, there are much more info to process. In this case, the process becomes slower, and sometimes the user may close the browser to do something else, he doesn't want to wait the finish. I am thinking about to create a thread to process this in background and send the report to email. But the problem of session lost continues.

Comment: Don't store that in the session... Bad design... Use smaller scopse (viewscoped e.g) or explicitly remove this from the session. That is the way to go.

Comment: But I don't store report data in the session. I just told like a sample case that users may run some reports with many informations. And this causes the processing takes many time. The session information itself is not a problem, I only just want to know if there is a way to detect that the user closed the browser when it was processing some long-term operation and kill the session/conversation used by him.

Comment: The session/conversation do not do any work. They are 'storage'. If you want to kill a process that is a completely different thing. You can 'kill' the session/conversation and the process still continues. Effectively the answer to the concrete question in the title is 'No'...